# x = 27 * 24 \ 4 / 2 – 4 + 2

Tags: math

Can someone help with the following MATH question.
Keep in mind the operator precedence.

x = 27 * 24 \ 4 / 2 – 4 + 2

Arithmetic and logical operators are evaluated in the following order of precedence:

Exponentiation (`^`)
Negation (`-`)
Multiplication and division (`*`, `/`)
Integer division (`\`)
Modulus arithmetic (`Mod`)
Addition and subtraction (`+`, `-`)

What is the result?

Comment: is \ meant to represent integer division?

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 27 * 24 = 648 \ 4 = 162 / 2 = 81 - 4 = 77 + 2 = 79

That appears to be pretty straightforward, unless I'm missing something

Comment: @Tawnos: I think you're missing that integer division has lower precedence than regular division.

Comment: Originally that order of operations put it on the same precedence level as multiplication and division. Since it's lower, the answer changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = ((27 * 24) \ (4 / 2)) - 4 + 2
  =  (648      \    2)    - 4 + 2
  =   324 - 4 + 2
  =   322
```